# The Improved Caesar Pig Latin Cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, cipher

The problem with the Caesar cipher is the resulting words are often unpronounceable.  The problem with Pig Latin is that it is easy to decode.  Why not combine them?

**Input**

A word consisting of the 26 english letters.

**Output**

First, change every consonant in the word to the next consonant in the alphabet.  So, b goes to c, d goes to f, and z goes to b.  Then, change every vowel to the next vowel in the alphabet (u goes to a).  Last, only if the first letter of the word is a consonant, move that letter to the end of the word and add "ay" to the end of the word.

Examples:

```
cat -> evday  
dog -> uhfay   
eel -> iim
```

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.
- Case does not matter.
- Vowels that will be used are A, E, I, O, and U

Comment: will we have capital letters in the input?

Comment: no, but you can if you want

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Very nice challenge, clearly presented.

Comment: Suggested test case: `z → bay`

Comment: jot ot e wisz opvisitvoph dupdiqv cav o fu puv vjopl ov jimqt xovj vji ecomovz vu qsupuapdi vji xusftvay

Comment: Suggested test case: `the → jivay`? (That is, if the word starts with multiple consonants, do we only move one of them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ù≥±╘├*Lâ■8O±âΓ║Θæ%º•
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=97f2f1d4c32a4c83fe384ff183e2bae99125a707&i=cat%0Adog%0Aeel%0Az%0Athe&m=2)

**Explanation**

```
Vc:tVv:tBcVc#{sL"ay"+}ML             #Full program, unpacked, implicit input
Vc:t                                 #Push consonants and ring translate input
    Vv:t                             #Push vowels and ring translate input
        BCvc#                        #Push first letter and tail of word, find number 
                                     #of occurrences to consonants
             {sL"ay"+}M              #If truthy (word starts with consonant)
                                     #swap stack, listify, add "ay"
                       L             #Listify stack (combines words that start with vowel)
```

I went through a few iterations and finally got it down to 20. My original solution was 53 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>96</s> 69 bytes

```ruby
->s{/^[^aeiou]/=~(r=s.tr'zb-yadehinotu','b-zefijopuva')?$'+$&+'ay':r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrdDoIgGADQe5/CC9dXE/W@jXoQhttHgtFKGEIDf3p18uZcHRdEyorm5javXc96lNoE3tHf2dG59Q4W0SQc5FNPxgcgIJpFKv0yNnwRLvcK6upUAya4uj0zeKA/0mDGQynfQEoQYQTeftCuW9wKW7JIFIuc70X@Aw)

Fun fact of the day: tr() matches strings right-to-left. I always assumed it was left-to-right.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>86</s> 85 bytes

Simple way. `chartr` has the charming and useful property that it can specify letter *ranges*, which save a few bytes.

-1 bytes by stealing @GB's [Ruby solution's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172313/81549) translation strings - upvote it!

```r
function(s)sub("^([^aeiou])(.*)","\\2\\1ay",chartr('zb-yadehinotu','b-zefijopuva',s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZLDsIgEADQvceYDTMGTOram4hNBgotxjCGj0l7eTTxrV4Z8WZG7Nm3JBkr1e4QZrzPHJL0B@HlTKDB2qu1E@@g/calFVSHMzsvYUtZWldaOXOEmJ7y7h9WuhKNiOC5AZ1@WWT9J4QX0PgC)

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 167 bytes

```java
s->{String r="",a="aeiouabcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb",c=s.split("")[0];s=a.indexOf(c)>5?s.substring(1)+c+"ux":s;for(var d:s.split(""))r+=a.charAt(a.indexOf(d)+1);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Lb8IwEITv/IqVJSS7CVY59EIaql56q3rgiHpwnAcOiZN6NykU5beneVDowVqPZvbTTq5atcrjY2/KunIE@aBlQ6aQaWM1mcrKh2ChC4UI78pYuCwA6iYqjAYkRcNoKxNDOXh8R87YbP8JymUopijA25XzPLv@PLaQQtjjanuZNbiQMV@FTCWmalSk4zQ75MeitPWXQ2q/T@efiPk6RIl1YYgzJvaPnwGGShobJ6ePlGuxfXoZ/CbCicnXwtMea05sg0FaOd4qB/HmH0E4b9jXB@Veid9BsfDWInAJNc6CC7o@mJrc6lGChBBeCwIwrYj5fyKusrtIkoJN/25mjGdcG4@UzcwSN9TujJSUsmpI1kOKUs6WuIElLi3zp7APqVR1XZz5qISYud1ifF3/Cw)

### Credits

- -7 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), using better types.
- -1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

Comment: [168 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY89b8IwEIZ3fsXJEpLdBKsMXUiD1KVb1YERMThOHBwSJ7XPKRTlt6f5oJTBOj@6V4/uLUQrVkV66nXV1BahGJh71CVX3kjUteFP0UKWwjn4ENrAdQHQ@KTUEhwKHEZb6xSqYUd3aLXJ9wcQNndsigK83zyv8zacxxYUxL1bba8zg40JCUVMRKZrLxKZqvxYnMrKNF/WYft9vvwkJJSx464pNVJC2P75EGlFBdcmzc6fikq2fWFujPjETVq6ZoEMiD@TSNWWtsJCunlQMBvEgsujsG/4IEpZsGaRzdBbAzbq@miqcu@HmUMH8a0hAJECSfgHaZ3/Q5aVZPp3s2M841Z5tGxmF7urdheHWcVrj7wZUqgoWboNLN3SkHAKh6C4aJryQkdibPZ2i/F1/S8)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

```
žMDÀ‡žNDÀ‡¬žNsåiÀ…ÿay
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/6D5fl8MNjxoWHt3nB2EcWgNkFh9emgniLTu8P7Hyf22l0uH9Crp2Cof3K@n8T04s4UrJT@dKTc0BAA)

**Explanation**

```
žMDÀ‡                   # replace each vowel with the next vowel in the alphabet
     žNDÀ‡              # replace each consonant with the next consonant in the alphabet
          ¬žNsåi        # if the first letter is a consonant
                À…ÿay   # rotate the word left and add "ay"
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Node.js 10.9.0](https://nodejs.org), <s>121</s> 116 bytes

Expects the input string in lower case.

```javascript
s=>(v=n=>2130466>>n&1)((a=Buffer(s).map(n=>(g=i=>v(n=n%61?n+1:97)^i?g(i):n)(v(n))))[0],a+='')?a:a.slice(1)+a[0]+'ay'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYpRC8IgFEbf@xmD8l6sMSsWDXTQ34iCy1IxTMdcg369@Rx9T4dzvictlIbJjfMuxIfORuYkFSwySLUXh@bYtkqFjUAAkpe3MXqChPWLRigPsNJJtRQM61b0gYvufMK76y047AJCSVh2bW5b4pIx7KmjOnk3aBDIqQTO6MPyEEOKXtc@WjBQDTRXiKsf@4j2j9XaF5u/)

#### Identifying vowels

To identify vowels, the helper function \$v\$ uses the following bitmask:

```
2130466 = 000001000001000001000100010
               ^     ^     ^   ^   ^
          zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba-
```

And does:

```javascript
(2130466 >> n) & 1
```

We don't need to mask out the relevant bits of \$n\$, because it is done implicitly. Below is the relevant quote from [the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-signed-right-shift-operator):

> Let *shiftCount* be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of *rnum*, that is, compute *rnum* & 0x1F.

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                      // s = input string
  ( v = n =>              // v = helper function taking n = ASCII code in [97..122]
    2130466 >> n & 1      //     and returning 1 if the corresponding character is a vowel
  )                       //     or 0 otherwise (see the previous paragraph)
  (                       // this statement will ultimately invoke v on a[0]
    ( a = Buffer(s)       //   convert s to a Buffer, holding ASCII codes
      .map(n =>           //   for each ASCII code n in there:
        ( g = i =>        //     g = recursive function taking i = vowel flag
          v(              //       update n and invoke v on the new value:
            n = n % 61 ?  //         if n is less than 122 (meaning less than 'z'):
              n + 1       //           increment n
            :             //         else:
              97          //           wrap around by setting n to 97 (meaning 'a')
          ) ^ i ?         //       if v(n) is not equal to i:
            g(i)          //         do recursive calls until it is
          :               //       else:
            n             //         stop recursion and return the new n
        )(v(n))           //     initial call to g with i = v(n)
      )                   //   end of map()
    )[0],                 //   invoke v on a[0]
    a += ''               //   coerce the updated Buffer back to a string
  ) ?                     // if a[0] is a vowel:
    a                     //   return the string as-is
  :                       // else:
    a.slice(1) + a[0]     //   move the leading consonant to the end
    + 'ay'                //   and append the 'ay' suffix
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>153</s> <s>121</s> <s>110</s> <s>99</s> 91 bytes

```python
lambda s:[s[1:]+s[0]+"ux",s][s[0]in'aeiou'].translate(8*".ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb.....")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBDoIwEEDRtZyi6WZAGqKuDAlepHYxQIFqaZEpClwexb94yR@W0Hl32ZrivlnsyxoZ5ZLkOVcpyZNK@TRzQUruYxygNn4ClYURHVkMOr4eeaarujFt9/BP27theo0U3viZl7XM9niyNX5kxIxjEioMIKD27U@tLQgG6x/cnWZQeXQYRuMCIwHFDUQTUxJtXw)

8 bytes shaved off due to a suggestion by [Matthew Jensen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87728/matthew-jensen)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by using string.translate() function: `lambda s:[s[1:]+s[0]+"ux",s][s[0]in'aeiou'].translate(8*".ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb.....")`

Comment: @MatthewJensen Clever! Usually I avoid `translate` in Python 2...

Comment: Coincidentally, it now also works for upper case as well

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 169 bytes

```sql
SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX(LEFT(a,1),'aeiou')=0,SUBSTRING(a,2,99)+LEFT(a,1)+'ay',a)FROM
(SELECT TRANSLATE(v,'aeioubcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz','eiouacdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb')a FROM t)s
```

Input is via a pre-existing table, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Performs the characters substitution first, using the ([new to SQL 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) `TRANSLATE` function, then checks the first character.

Annoying long mostly due to SQL keyword length.

Answer (score 3):

## Shell script, 70 bytes

```bash
tr a-z b-{|tr eiou{bfjpv fjpvbeioua|sed -E 's/^([^aeiou])(.*)/\2\1ay/'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIIVG3SiFJt7oGyEzNzC@tTkrLKihTABFJIH5iTXFqioKuq4J6sX6cRnRcIkgwVlNDT0tTP8YoxjCxUl/9//@M1JycfIXy/KKcFAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>102</strike> 97 bytes

```hs
h(c:r)|elem c"aeiou"=c:r|True=r++c:"ay"
f s=h["ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb"!!(fromEnum y-97)|y<-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncw7D4IwFAXgnV9RbxwgDbORWDc3N92MQy0XivSBfagQ/jt2kO3LyTlHct@jUssic1G5YkaFmgjg2NkILEXz1UVkjlJRAR8ha4hn8gYo6qZr5dP2SpshvpwPb/75jtMDNpu8cVafTNRkLPe7Yh4Ppb8vLpq0HWK4BHc2W08pkPJIgNL0mWneGVbbjJDUA8ED/FnbdiWiWhkkrpxg@QE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
,ṙ¥1y
ØẹçØḄçṙḢe©ØḄƊ®⁾ayx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4c6Zh5YaVnIdnvFw187Dy4HUjpbDy4GiD3csSj20Esw/1nVo3aPGfYmVFf///0/JTwcA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) (use the two-char syntax rather than quotes).

Comment: [Unfortunately far longer sane, non-sneaky version](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4c6Zh5YaVnIdnvFw187Dy4HUjpbDy4GihtaPGuYkVj5qmHus6@GO7fqpYKljXYcW/v//PzU1BwA) (1-byte shorter [sneaky](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4c6Zh5YaVnIdnvFw187Dy4HUjpbDy4Giho8a5iRWPmqYq/Jwx3b9VLDEsa5DC////5@Snw4A) equivalent). I won't be able to update this within the next few hours, but *do* point out if you find improvements.

Comment: Use `⁾ay` for a byte. The `©` could go after the `e` since that is what you are storing. I have `ØẹØḄ,żṙ€¥1ẎyṙḢe©ØḄƊ®⁾ayẋ`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 50 bytes

```
T`uo`aei\oub-df-hj-np-tv-zb
^([^aeiou])(.*)
$2$1ay
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyShND8hMTUzJr80STclTTcjSzevQLekTLcqiStOIzoOKJVfGqupoaelyaVipGKYWPn/f3JiCVdKfjpXamoOAA) Link includes test cases. Similar approach to the R answer. Explanation:

```
T`uo`aei\oub-df-hj-np-tv-zb
```

`o` refers to the other set, i.e. `aei\oub-df-hj-np-tv-zb`, which expands to `aeioubcdfghjlkmnpqrstvwxyzb`, so `uo` expands to `uaeioubcdfghjlkmnpqrstvwxyzb`. This results in the following transliteration:

```
uaeioubcdfghjlkmnpqrstvwxyzb
aeioubcdfghjlkmnpqrstvwxyzb
```

The second `u` and `b` are ignored as they can never be matched, so this provides the desired cipher. (Note that in Retina 1 you can of course use `v` instead of `aei\ou` for a 5 byte saving.)

```
^([^aeiou])(.*)
$2$1ay
```

If the first letter is not a vowel, rotate it to the end and suffix `ay`.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>94</s> 92 bytes

```
i:0(?v"a"%
2%?!v\~r:5g
a2r}<vr+ad*
ol?!;>4g
ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb
1   1   1     1     1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMO@TClRSZXLSNVesSymrsjKNJ0r0aio1qasSDsxRYsrP8de0drOJJ0rNTklLTM9Iys/Oyc3r6C0sKi4pCyxvKKyKonLUEFBAYbh5P//qak5AA)

*Edit: Saved 2 bytes by taking input mod 97 rather than 32, so the dictionary could start at the beginning of the line. Previous version:*

```
i:0(?v84*%
2%?!v\~r:5g
37r}<vr*46*
ol?!;>4g
 ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb
 1   1   1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 149 bytes

```
func[s][c:"aeioua.bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb"t: copy""foreach p s[append t c/(1
+ index? find c p)]if 7 < index? find c t/1[move t tail t append t"ay"]t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEX3PcUwK0WwdCUUwTu4DVmkk0kbbZOYprX18rEbRVw93of3I@t8ZS1kYepsJkdilIJqVGz9pI4NadN2t3s/uPCIY5qfy/pqMNVAPqyIxkdW1EGAUagQ2GlIQOWuKg5gneblAmYjEIS9tAZOcP7bU1mJwc@8dUnZfsPnB9WKMskconUJDCCphMXXtG9/jLnHIr8B)

As (almost) always, the longest entry

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 56 bytes

```perl
y/a-z/ecdfighjok-npuq-tvaw-zb/;s/^([^aeiou])(.*)/$2$1ay/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDkBADADAu3c4IKmGxMlThKQoFtFlF@HxasbysRaqDxK8yF0/mHGaZYHNnjv4i254WywdNlHVEBs56zhKkxjDPMzoQdWOfNDLGDCvn1hvZHMK9gc)

Comment: Do you need the `-`s between `c` and `d` or `g` and `h`?

Comment: @Neil no I don't. I wrote a program to compress the ranges... and got the logic wrong :) Thanks.

Comment: Normally in such cases you write `<s>58</s> 56 bytes` in the header and many people add a "Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil." or some such when they are helped in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 197 bytes

```fs
let f(s:string)=
 let a="aeiouabcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb"
 new string(s|>Seq.map(fun c->a.[a.IndexOf(c)+1])|>Seq.toArray)|>(fun x->if a.IndexOf(x.[0])>5 then x.Substring(1)+(string x.[0])+"ay"else x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NaoQwFIX3PsUlMJAghs6imxYDXRYKXcxSXES9cTLVxEliJ5Z5d5vRQjf373z3HOWL0Rq7rgMGUNS/@OC06VmZweMiSyJR21k2baf68@VrGM10dT583@Ly05AMDN5g/6H@Lk545aOcqJoNtIWQvJL83XQYPxVtWX6s2c4E@@acXNK2obEQWsE/Gnn1VDPxDOGMSeWnufnLOLKc7iPsUE7kQnDwCJFla0VaGcgr6WyfKuJAargL@NA@cB3QwRaXDKAQMCWboAyQg4dSwMGTTaHq0RhbfwE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 107 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/./g,y=>(z='aeiouabcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb')[z.search(y)+1]).replace(/^([^aeiou])(.+)/,'$2$1ay')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxLCoMwFEDReZchQvLQRuxcNyIKMT7jJ5o0sda4@bR0UiidHrh34jt3wo5muzozdmgXvc7oQ1@EoygPZtEoLpBmLJOpL0p6FoTjqB@8FV0vh2lWy2ru1m378/BnS6A6mUNuxUA9JHkN30VDq@bT1kBZAllK4lucc08gCL06rZApLWlPI8G3CODyo52WfxRRvTW8AA)

Expects input in lowercase.

Replaces each character of the string with a the one after it in the string `'aeiouabcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzb'`, and then piglatinifies anything with an initial consonant.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 112 bytes

```php
<?=strtr(($s=strstr(aeiou,($s=$argn)[0])?$s:substr($s,1).$s[0].ux),join(range(a,z)),ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb);
```

or

```php
<?=strtr(($s=strstr(aeiou,($argn)[0])?$argn:substr($s,1).$s[0].ux),join(range(a,z)),ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb);
```

assume lower case input. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0f21a36cfe3f98e069799d069c4183eb4d1b2ca).

---

You could as well use
`strtr($s,uzbcadfgehjklminpqrsotvwxy,range(a,z))` instead of
`strtr($s,range(a,z),ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL (SBCS), 57 bytes

```apl
{a←⎕A{(⍺~⍵)⍵}'AEIOU'⋄('AY',⍨1⌽⊢)⍣(∊/⊃¨⍵a)⊢(⊂⍵⍳⍨∊a)⌷∊1⌽¨a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///303hUdsEhepEIPmob6pjtcaj3l11j3q3agJxrbqjq6d/qLrCo@4WBQ11x0h1nUe9Kwwf9ex91LUIqGCxxqOOLv1HXc2HVgBVKyRqAoU1HnU1ATmPejcDlQKlgYI924E0SNehFYm1XEBbwFa6HVqhoO7sGKKuoO7i7w4kXV19gGSIh6v6//8A)

Takes input in uppercase only! (Because `⎕A` is uppercase alphabet)

- `⎕A{(⍺~⍵)⍵}'AEIOU'`: Vector of consonants and vowels
- `(⊂⍵⍳⍨∊a)⌷∊1⌽¨a`: Uses indices of each letter of the word in the normal alphabet (`⊂⍵⍳⍨∊a`) to index (`⌷`) into the cipher `∊1⌽¨a`.
- `('AY',⍨1⌽⊢)⍣(∊/⊃¨⍵a)`: Moves first letter to the end and appends 'AY', if the first letter is a consonant.

Thanks for the cool challenge!

Answer (score 0):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 202 bytes

```bash
class C {b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z} 
class V {a,e,i,o,u}
c:
{@C,@V}=>{{c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z,b},{e,i,o,u,a}}
p:
([]+)$1 *=>$1/$ @V _
(@C+)$1 ([]*)$2=>$2 $1 ay/$ _
```